# notation: precedence of conditional when multiple variables

Tags: notation, conditioning

In expressions such as
$  P(X,Y|Z) $
and $I(X; Y|Z)$  (mutual information)

there are two interpretations for a student, and the correct one does not seem to be mentioned in textbooks.

1. "joint probability of (X and Y) given Z" and "(mutual information of X and Y) given Z"
2. "joint probability of X and (Y given Z)" and "mutual information of X and (Y given Z)"

For probability I think #1 is the correct one.  But then, there could be an alternate notation
that would be clearer, like $P(X|Z, Y|Z)$ and $I(X|Z; Y|Z)$.

I am afraid I have missed something very basic.

Comment: Could you explain what (2) might actually mean?  Perhaps you could give an example?

Comment: Yes, (2) makes no sense at all. Your answer is kind.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with version 2., I think, is that (Y given Z) makes no sense. It is not a random variable itself, and only makes sense as P(Y|Z). The comment of whuber provided this answer to me.

Comment: (+1) It is an unfortunate reality that many people think "$Y|Z$" is a random variable.  Your answer is great by pointing out that "(it) only makes sense as $P(Y|Z)$" (although more precisely, you might mean 
"$P(Y \leq y | Z)$" or "$E(Y|Z)$").